# Read table in R with spaces in path

Tags: r, sublimetext3

I'm trying to read an external file from inside an R script ran in Sublime Text. The problem is that i want to read it specifying the relative path (just the name in this case because they are in the same folder). It works perfect, EXCEPT when there are spaces in the absolute path of the file.

My code for reading is:

```
t <- read.csv('data.csv',header=F)$V1
```

But if the folder i currently have the files in have any spaces in it's path, let's say..

```
/Users/A/B/C D/E
```

It fails (doesn't find the file), but if i delete the space in the path or change it, it works:

```
/Users/A/B/C_D/E
```

I've tried to make many bypasses around it, trying to parse the path with `system()` and `setwd()` but it's always the same problem when it's a space in the path.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: OSX 10.11, but is not an os problem it's more related to Sublime Text (or r prompt) behaviour, because when i read from some ides, it works.

Answer (score 3):

Escape the path for spaces, so

```
/Users/A/B/C\\ D/E
# always remember that R requires \\, not \
```

Comment: In R you'll need two backslashes as one is an escape character

Comment: That's not my problem, im not inputing the path (which is exactly what i wanna avoid..), im using the relative path. Read again, my command is: t <- read.csv('data.csv',header=F)$V1, im pointing to a file in the same folder, the problem is when R 'internally' reads the path.

Comment: Doesn't work...